# VIM doesn't open immediately after I press enter

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, vim

## Original question

I am using the following software:

- WSL with Ubuntu installed from the Microsoft Store.
- Windows Terminal and oh-my-zsh

I have the following undesirable behaviors which was not the case when I first installed `vim`:

- Typing `vim` into my command prompt and pressing enter suspends the prompt. When I try to get out by pressing Ctrl+C, that's when vim actually opens. It seems to work properly, but I am frustrated that it won't open immediately after I press enter.
- Opening a file with `vim filename.txt` does not open the file. When I press Ctrl+C `vim` will open as mentioned above, but the file is blank. In contrast, when I run `cat filename.txt` I get the content of the file printed out to my standard output.
- `vim` opens all files in read only mode unless I do `sudo vim`. Any commands to quit or persist file changes must be followed by an exclamation mark

Has anyone ever observed this behavior? How can I fix it? Thanks

## Edits

### response to @muru

```
➜ type -a vim
vim is /usr/bin/vim
vim is /bin/vim
➜ printenv TERM
xterm-256color
```

`vim -Nu NONE` also exhibits the same behavior, it suspends the prompt until I press Ctrl+C. I guess that means the issue might not be related to `vimrc`?

### response to @NotTheDr01ds

- `wsl -e vim` successfully triggers a vim instance with no delay in Powershell (it works as expected).
- `wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc` appears to open a `bash-5.0$` prompt. Following this with a `vim` command also triggers a vim instance with no delay in Powershell (it works as expected).
- `wsl -u root` followed by appears to open a `root@LAPTOP_NAME:/mnt/c/Users/username#` prompt. Following this with a `vim` command also triggers a vim instance with no delay in Powershell (it works as expected).

Comment: Add the output of `type -a vim`, `printenv TERM` to your post, please. Also, try without your vimrc (`vim -Nu NONE`).

Comment: A few more "isolating the problem" troubleshooting steps.  Since this is WSL, try some of these (from PowerShell) - `wsl -e vim` (delay or immediate?  If immediate, could be something in the profile/rc).  Likewise, `wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc` (assuming your shell is `bash`), then `vim`.  Same problem or no?  If both of those have the same issue, then `wsl -u root`, then `vim`.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, Thanks for commenting. I just ran all the commands in powershell and they work as expected (please see edits to original question for more details).

Comment: I do not have a `~/.bash_profile` . I have made no manual modifications to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`. However, I did recently notice that the terminal will prompt me for my sudo password every now and then...

Comment: Would it be useful to provide the contents of `bashrc` or `profile`?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds  I am using `Oh My Zsh`  combined with the Windows Terminal. The sudo password prompting occurs sporadically when I Windows Terminal. This typically occurs after a restart (??). `command vim` has the exact same results and behaves in the same way. Please let me know if you still want to see the full contents of `bashrc` and/or `profile`

Comment: I just logged an issue on [github](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9917). I also stumbled across some possibly relevant stuff [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5790). Finally I have noticed additional strange behavior, namely that `vim .zshrc` opens what looks like a completely blank file while `cat .zshrc` shows that the file is not blank.

Comment: Yes. Running vim with the the verbose option turned on revealed that it was having trouble accessing my local X Server. I had added an `export DISPLAY` statement to my zshrc script to be able to run GUI apps from WSL with XLaunch. Removing the statement solved the problem.

Comment: Good to hear you found it!  I've taken advantage of the Stack "auto-move comments to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124407/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-user32882)" to clean this up a bit.  I'm going to flag the comments for removal as "no longer needed".  Could you provide the information on the `DISPLAY` issue as a self-answer?  It could be useful to someone else who comes along and finds this question.

Comment: @user32882 I just came across this and realized that we never really "closed it out" - Could you add your solution as an *answer*?  It appears that it's actually helped some people, and (a) would be more visible as an answer, (b) will get you the upvotes on it as well.  Thanks!